# How to change the type of an input with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a modern password input, with a toggle password button that changes the type of input.

Problem:

I did all of the things below but when I test it and click on the icon, it is not changing anything.

```js
function toggle_password() {
  const input = getElementById("toggle_password");
  if (input.type === "password") {
    input.type = "text";
  } else {
    input.type = "password";
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
  <i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true" id="toggle_password" onClick="toggle_password()"></i>
  <input id="toggle_password" class="align from_Input password" type="password" placeholder="Password" required />
</div>
```

And here I made the `toggle_password` function.

Comment: *"message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: getElementById is not defined",* Unless you made a getElementById method in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using same id in two different inputs. Since the id `toggle_password` appears first on the `<i>` element, `<i>` was being taken into  account

Also `document` was missing in
`const input = document.getElementById("password");`

**PROBLEM:**  Check the log when you click on the icon, its saving `<i>` in the input variable.

```js
function toggle_password() {
  const input = document.getElementById("toggle_password");
  console.log(input)
  if (input.type === "password") {
    input.type = "text";
  } else {
    input.type = "password";
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
  <i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true" id="toggle_password" onClick="toggle_password()"></i>
  <input id="toggle_password" class="align from_Input password" type="password" placeholder="Password" required />
</div>
```

**Solution:**

Give a different id to password `<input>` element and use that id to get the element. So you will save `<input>` element in input variable.

```js
function toggle_password() {
  const input = document.getElementById("password");
  console.log(input)
  if (input.type === "password") {
    input.type = "text";
  } else {
    input.type = "password";
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
  <i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true" id="toggle_password" onClick="toggle_password()"></i>
  <input id="password" class="align from_Input password" type="password" placeholder="Password" required />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, it's `document.getElementById`, `getElementById` is a method inside `document` object.

Second, the icon and input has the same id, the `id` attribute should be unique ( I changed the input id to `toggle_password__input` ).

```js
function toggle_password() {
      const input = document.getElementById("toggle_password__input");
      if (input.type === "password") {
        input.type = "text";
      } else {
        input.type = "password";
      }
    }
```

```html
<div>
            <i
              class="fa fa-eye"
              aria-hidden="true"
              id="toggle_password"
              onClick="toggle_password()"
            >toggle</i>
            <input
              id="toggle_password__input"
              class="align from_Input password"
              type="password"
              placeholder="Password"
              required
            />
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify both, your markup and your script as demonstrated below:

```js
document.querySelector(".fa-eye").onclick=ev=>{
 let inp=ev.target.nextElementSibling;
 inp.type=inp.type==="password"?"text":"password";
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
  <i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <input class="align from_Input password" type="password" placeholder="Password" required />
</div>
```